# Will we get our reputation back if bounty is not answered in SOF [2019]?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, bounties

I saw many other old posts which states that we won't get our reputation back but I would like to know whether stackoverflow has added an option for it or not?
If there is no feature till now please consider adding that feature.

Comment: Per https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty **all bounties are paid upfront and are not refundable under any circumstances**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing's changed. The point of a bounty is to get *attention* not an answer. This doesn't necessarily guarantee an answer. Our policies on that haven't changed. If you have the rep, and want the answer you'll just have to keep posting (bigger) bounties until you get it, and see if the extra attention will help.

A bounty is best used as a *last ditch* effort to get an answer, and if its a properly interesting/difficult question, it may not be answerable anyway.

What gets you an answer, aside from having the right person seeing it is, well posting the best possible question you can - just enough code for someone to work out what's wrong, any *relevant* errors (don't just dump your logs) and so on.